# How to include space in decrypting a sentence with space using polybius square cipher?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

```
 char[][] matrix = {
                  {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'},
                  {'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K'},
                  {'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'},
                  {'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U'},
                  {'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'}
                };
```

```
System.out.println("DECIPHER");
sc.nextLine();
            
System.out.println("ENTER CIPHERTEXT:  ");
ctext = sc.nextLine();
String deciphered = decipher(ctext, matrix);
System.out.println(deciphered);


public static String decipher(String ctext, char[][] matrix) {
            StringBuilder deciphered = new StringBuilder(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < ctext.length(); i += 2) {
              int row = Character.getNumericValue(ctext.charAt(i)) - 1;
              int col = Character.getNumericValue(ctext.charAt(i + 1)) - 1;
              deciphered.append(matrix[row][col]);
            }                 
            return deciphered.toString();
     }
```

When encrypting a plaintext, the result is good and it includes the space. On the other hand, when decrypting a ciphertext, the result shows with an error about its index which tells that its out of bounds.

[This is the error that it showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/antD6.png)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -2 ou
t of bounds for length 5
    at CASESTUDY_FINALS.POLYBIUS_SQUARE.decipher(POLYBIUS_SQUARE.java:111)
```

I'm expecting that it would also include the space. Can you help me look for the error and help me fix it by including the space in decrypting it using Polybius Square Cipher using Java. Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to handle the case where there is a space in the input character stream.  Why do you expect that a space will not produce an error?  Have you considered adding a check for a space character in the input and skipping it when you see it?

Comment: So, which is line 111 (or 109) in your code?

Comment: Are you aware that [`Character.getNumericValue (char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) may return a value of -1 or -2?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer
My line 109 is 
int col = Character.getNumericValue(ctext.charAt(i + 1)) - 1;
My line 111 is
deciphered.append(matrix[row][col]);

Comment: So, what is the output from `System.out.println (Character.getNumericValue (' '));` ?